# rtsp-sink(RTSPStreamer) DirectShow.Net filter based RTSP server causes high latency in complete network and even slowdown the network speed by 90%

Tags: c++, video-streaming, video-processing, rtsp, directshow.net

Ref: I have a RTSP media server that sends video via TCP streaming.I am using rtsp-sink(RTSPStreamer) DirectShow.Net filter based RTSP server which is developed in C++.Where as The Wrapper app is developed using C#.

The problem i am facing is the moment RTSP server start streaming,it affects the system level internet connection & drops internet connection speed by 90 percent.

I wanted to get your input on how it would be possible? (if at all).Because it impacts on system level internet connection not the very app level.

For Example:- My normal internet connection speed is 25 mbps. It suddenly drops to 2 mbps , whenever the RTSP streaming started in the app's server tab.

Sometimes even disables the internet connection in the system(Computer) where the app is running.

I'm asking you because I consider you an expert so please bear with me on this "maybe wild" question and thanks ahead.

...of all the things I've lost, I miss my mind the most.

[image: RTSPSolution]
[image: RTSPSender]

Code Snippet of RTSPSender.CPP

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CStreamingServer
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
UsageEnvironment* CStreamingServer::s_pUsageEnvironment = NULL;
CHAR CStreamingServer::s_szDefaultBroadCastIP[] = "239.255.42.42";
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CStreamingServer::CStreamingServer(HANDLE hQuit)
    : BasicTaskScheduler(10000)
    , m_hQuit(hQuit)
    , m_Streams(NAME("Streams"))
    , m_bStarting(FALSE)
    , m_bSessionReady(FALSE)
    , m_pszURL(NULL)
    , m_rtBufferingTime(UNITS * 2)
{
    s_pUsageEnvironment = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*this);
    rtspServer = NULL;
    strcpy_s(m_szAddress,"");
    strcpy_s(m_szStreamName,"stream");
    strcpy_s(m_szInfo,"media");
    strcpy_s(m_szDescription,"Session streamed by \"RTSP Streamer DirectShow Filter\"");
    m_nRTPPort = 6666;
    m_nRTSPPort = 8554;
    m_nTTL = 1;
    m_bIsSSM = FALSE;
}
```

Edited:WireShark logs:
[WireShark logs at the time of RTSP streaming started](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6fz0hC97RzBcDBndjhYNHZHbjQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: More data required:
1. Are RTSP Server and RTSPSink running on the same machine ? 
2. Do you have wireshark logs ? If yes, Please share.

Comment: @Manoj Thanks for your response. Answer to your first question is.. Yes..its running on the same machine.Basically RTSP server developed using RTSPSink Directshow filter.So its in the same dot net application.I have edited my question with attached wireshark logs(Edited:WireShark logs:).Please let me know if any other thing is needed.

Comment: Few Suggessions : 
1. Can you try with Unicast streaming ? Both TCP and UDP (Because multicast(Broadcast) TCP will fill your network with numerous Acknowledgements and will eventually slows down the network )?
2. Can you try connecting your network to 5 GHz AP if it is not ?
3. http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/ Can you try with different port numbers that are mentioned in this link ?

Try the above things and then let's to narrow down the issue.

Thanks

PS : Let us try to fix it here itself.

Comment: @Manoj we found your suggestions to narrow down the issue really awesome & workable.Let me explain what we have done.Step-1:-We purchased a new powerful router which has more data transfer rate & functionality like Multicasting enable/disable options in it.Step 2:-Testing RTSP server with different port now solved our network disconnection issues due to more data transfer rate in the new router maybe..Current Issue:-We are not able to get the stream out side of LAN.There is no error when playing in VLC.Player play button starts playing but no video/audio showing.Any suggestion from your side.